# How to geocode California using country parameter in the GET request

Tags: get, here-api

I am using here api
and i was able to fetch the long, lat of most countries
but i couldn't get information from california using 
the below GET request

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=XXXXXXXXX&app_code=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY&country=california&city=los+angeles
```

is there something wrong with my GET request, although it worked well for country=Egypt&city=Cairo

Answer (score 2):

My bad...

The answer was simply that california is a state of a USA country, so the problem is solved with replacing 'country' with 'state':

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=XXXXXXXXX&app_code=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY&state=california&city=los+angeles
```